# PayPal Smart Button

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to customize PayPal buttons using that method:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/customize-button/

```
var FUNDING_SOURCES = [
    paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL,
     paypal.FUNDING.CARD
];

// Loop over each funding source / payment method
FUNDING_SOURCES.forEach(function(fundingSource) {

    // Initialize the buttons
    var button = paypal.Buttons({



    // Check if the button is eligible
    if (button.isEligible()) {



        // Render the standalone button for that funding source
        button.render('#paypal-button-container');

    }


});
```

Buttons appear correctly, but I trying to add space between them, how can I do it? I tried also style 'vertical', but still they appear without space.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your forEach loop, when you render things into the container (`button.render(`) , also add whatever spacing you want.

Comment: I have tried your way but it still apper same way: pp button under card button and no space between them

Answer (score 0):

Took me awhile but I have found solution, if somone would ever need in style:

```
      #paypal-button-container{
}

.paypal-buttons-layout-horizontal {

      margin: 5px;
}
```